# Problem regarding Trigonometry Multiple Angles

Tags: trigonometry

Well, I know that this is not a homework help site. This isn't a homework, but rather I want to clear a probable misconception that I have on trigonometry submultiple and multiple angles. Here is the question.

> Determine the smallest positive value of x(in degrees) for which
>   $tan (x+100°)=tan (x+50).tan x. tan(x-50)$

I proceeded in the following way.
$\frac {tan (x+100)}{tan (x-50)} = tan(x+50)tan x$
$\frac{sin(x+100)cos(x-50)}{cos(x+100)sin(x-50)}=\frac{sin(x+50).sin x}{cos(x+50).cos x}$.
Doing componendo-dividendo on both sides, and simplifying them in the form of compound angles I am getting, 
$\frac{sin (2x+50)}{sin 150}=\frac{cos 50}{-cos(2x+50)}.$
Cross multiplying, and multiplying 2 on both sides, and on LHS, using the multiple angle formula ,I get,
$sin (4x+100)=-2 sin 150. cos 50$
$\implies sin (4x°+100°)=-cos 50° (sin 150= cos 60= 1/2)$
$\implies sin(4x+100°)=-sin(90°+50°)$
$\implies 4x+100=140$
$\implies x=10$
But the answer is given x=30. It only comes if in step 1,
I use the following step, 
$sin (4x+100)=sin (270-50)$
But then, if $smallest$ positive value is required, why I will chose the third quadrant instead of second quadrant?  Is the answer wrong? Or I am having some misconceptions?  Is my procedure correct?

Answer (score 0):

everything seems fine until you get to the line $$\sin(4x+100)=-\cos 50$$which you now equate to $$\sin(90+50)$$ which is not correct because $$\sin(90+50)=\sin90\cos 50+\cos 90\sin50=\cos 50$$

Instead, use $$-\cos 50=\cos(180-50)=\cos130=\sin(90-130)=\sin(-40)$$

Then you have $$4x+100=\begin{cases}-40+n.360     \\180+40+n.360\end{cases}$$

Comment: Why? Isn't this associated angles working here?

Comment: $sin (90+\theta)= -cos \theta$. Isn't it?

Comment: $\sin(90+\theta)=\sin90\cos\theta+\cos90\sin\theta$

Comment: So sin 90=1, cos 90=0, so you get $sin (90+\theta)=cos\theta$

Comment: yes I agree....

Comment: Or just $-\cos 50^\circ = -\sin 40^\circ$

Comment: $=\sin(-40)$...quite so